# new constructor with a string

Tags: actionscript-3

Instead of many if conditionals, I want to call a constructor according to a string value

```
var valueString:String = "myNewClassB";
var value:Class = valueString as Class; 

new value() // new value() == new myNewClassB()
```

I know it's gonna fail, I need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do that, there are two ways, either assign classes to a list of classes made for an example in a object:

```
var list:Object = {
 classA: FirstClass,
 classB: SecondClass,
 classC: ThirdClass
}
```

and than call them by a string:

```
var desiredObject:* = new (list["classA"] as Class)();
```

or you could also use getDefinitionBtName but than if you want to get a class you need to provide a full name (with the package)

```
var desiredClass = getDefinitionByName( "com.somedomain.SomeClass" );
```

If you are laoding an SWF content and than want to get a class from it you should use that loader `loaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition( "....class" );`

you can also check if a class is defined by:

```
loaderInfo.applicationDomain.hasDefinition( "....class" );
```

- link: [ApplicationDomain.getDefinition](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#getDefinition%28%29)
- link: [ApplicationDomain.hasDefinition](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#hasDefinition%28%29)
- link: [LoaderInfo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html)

Comment: +1 this totally beats my answer ;-) Add some links to the official docs and I'll delete mine (it will be redundant).

Answer (score 6):

```
var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName("myNewClassB");
var instance = new ClassReference();
```

That's the basics, bud.